# android EditTextView Password mask not visible for custom font family

Tags: android, android-edittext

EditTextView Password mask not visible when i changed font family of editText to custom font(Helvetica).
Its not working even  when i try to use  setTransformationMethod().
Help would be appreciated.

Regards
vijay

Comment: have you try another font or default ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the attribute android:password="true" for the textView in the layout file

Comment: this should be comment.

Comment: <EditText
               android:id="@+id/et_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

Comment: android:password="true"  has been deprecated

Comment: @Vijay0887,i mean when you using other or default is shown password mask ?

Comment: @Vijay0887 Try setting input type as textPassword programmatically after you have set the font and done any other changes to the editText